# OAuth 2.0 for APIs

Tags: api, oauth

I'm not an OAuth expert, and I saw the first release as extremely complex for handling the "flow dance" inside server side code (or, at least for me, quite impossibile).

Does OAuth 2.0 introduce new ways to accomplish an authentication that is suitable for APIs?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be careful not to confuse authentication and authorization. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Simple REST API access control or delegated third-party authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience OAuth 2 is much easier to implement than OAuth 1. If you want to see a quick overview check out these two flow charts for comparison. [OAuth 1](http://si0.twimg.com/images/dev/oauth_diagram.png) and [OAuth 2](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/html/images/oauth2_flow.png).

If you're going to implement OAuthentication I'd recommend checking out existing libraries first.